# Is yoga haram? Please clarify

Tags: halal-haram, school, hindu

Is yoga haram? I am not referring to a Hinduism worship related yoga, I am talking about exercise yoga. In my school, we are forced to do yoga, is it haram? I am hoping for it to be halal in this exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's purely related to physical exercise, there is no cause for yoga to be prohibited/haram itself!

Islam doesn't restrain enjoying fun & sports to a certain level and also supports physical fitness as there is a reference in hadith as a physically strong believer!

But if any other prohibited matters are mixed while practicing yoga like co-practicing of adult male & female, prohibited dress up, uttering any words or referring to any such contemplation which directly or indirectly conflicts to the basic Islamic beliefs or and much more, then that practice of yoga would be surely prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

See the writings of Al Biruni:Yoga Sutras of Patanjali (or for the more advanced reader his translation of Yoga Vasistha or My India).
Sheikh Muhammad Gnauth : Bahr al Hayat or
Muhammad Dara Shikuh; Majma il Bahrain; The mingling of two oceans or for the benefits of the yoga poses;
Ashraf Nizami: Namaz. The Yoga of Islam

So as to understand that the current objectors have no (wanting to) understand of the deeper meaning of yoga and that there is no conflict here. That the yoga practices and teachings deepen each and every religious experience to it's source.
What the objectors are doing is erring in the practice of perpetuating erroneous logic, presenting it as if there is any substance of truth to their argumentation. Yoga's practice might however arrive at a conclusion that long as the mind is engaged in any practice of religious activity with in mind a certain control, or outcome whereas when this can be let go of, in particular for men, the hearts minds and intelligence might have a very different outcome of perspective.
To understand the fear of current orthodox thought and a striving to a stricter return to this see: Shahab Ahmed: Before Orthodoxy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

IMO yes and I’m not about to pull a page of letters instead read this for better information Sheikh Assimalhakeen and may Allah have mercy on him and forgive his sins and yours too https://www.assimalhakeem.net/2014/03/19/is-it-permissible-to-practice-yoga-with-no-music-meditation-etc-purely-for-exercising-purpose-the-class-is-for-ladies-and-taught-by-a-lady-assalamu-alaikumyoga-its-origins-and-the-ruling-on-prac/

Comment: This shiekh doesn’t follow in any of the 4 madhabs so it is best to avoid his answers.

Comment: That's irrationally uncalled for. Were there madhhabs at the time of the Sahabah? Despite being a necessity is there however a divine injunction that following one of the four schools of fiqh is a firm and rigorous obligation? When he relies primarily on the Qur'an and Sunnah what cause is there to reject everything he says?