# is doing certain stretching of yoga haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I know that doing yoga is haram as it is part of Hinduism. But what about doing certain stretching that matches with some yoga stretching. I follow a stretching routine that has some yoga stretches like

**downward facing dog** - You kind of need to bend your body like a dog.

**Dynamic Frog pose** - Be in a frog position.

**is doing those haram?** Note that i am not doing yoga. Just a stretching routine to stretch my legs.

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/69634/is-yoga-haram-please-clarify?rq=1

Comment: @valikaze125 that does not answer my question

Comment: it's not haram as long as your intention is purely for exercise and not to do yoga or imitate the Hindus in any type of way. and Allah knows best.